# ImportError: No module named psycogreen.gevent

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I tried run odoo 8 instance with workers=1, but i getting this error.

`ImportError: No module named psycogreen.gevent`.

I have tried so many tutorial to resolve this. nothing works.
Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Per Odoo comminity link you should try following command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo stop
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install psycogreen
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo start
```

You can check following link.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/6852

Answer (score 1):

You do not need psycogreen at all.  Just have this code run before you connect to postgresql.

```
from psycopg2 import extensions

def gevent_wait_callback(conn, timeout=None):
    """A wait callback useful to allow gevent to work with Psycopg."""
    while 1:
        state = conn.poll()
        if state == extensions.POLL_OK:
            break
        elif state == extensions.POLL_READ:
            wait_read(conn.fileno(), timeout=timeout)
        elif state == extensions.POLL_WRITE:
            wait_write(conn.fileno(), timeout=timeout)
        else:
            raise ConnectorError("Bad result from poll: %r" % state)

extensions.set_wait_callback(gevent_wait_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

After `pip install psycogreen` use:

```
from psycogreen import gevent
gevent.patch_psycopg()
```